# Adjusting image size using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Hello I have made a website where my header adjusts to the size of the screen, but the contents inside the header are not adjusting. For instance, there is an image that is unable to adjust itself and ends up leaving the header to go under it once the browser window is resized. Font is also not adjusting.

I have already tried min-width and max-width but it is not working. I am using `@media` queries and was wondering if there is someway to use this query to make the contents inside the header to adjust themselves along with the header.

My `<header>` style is as follows:

```css
header {
    position: relative;
    width: Auto;
    height: 239px;
    background: #FED93F;
}
```

Edit

What I have done is added a `<header>` tag and placed two images, along with a heading inside it. In the heading, the text does not adjust it self. In the image, the first image is a logo and the second is an image on the far right. The logo is placed somewhere at the left, with the text in the middle of it all.

```
<header>
<img src="images/Logo_image.png"  style="margin-left:50px; margin-top:50px"/>
<h1>Company name</h1>
<p>Tag Line</p>
<img src="images/side_image.png" style="position: relative; align: right; float:right" />
</header>
```

When all this stuff is added, I want it to adjust itself to the size of the window just as the main header does. But it is not being so.

The CSS of the Text:

```
header h1
{
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 72px;
    color: #6A1111;
    position: absolute;
    left: 212px;
    top: 78px;

}


header p
{
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #404041;
    position:absolute;
    margin: -35px 0 0 250px;
}
```

Comment: can you please show your html code also.

Comment: What does your html look like? Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
header {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:239px;
    background:#FED93F;
}
header img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The element inside your header should be 100% wide.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this -

```css
header img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
header {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:239px;
    background:#FED93F;
}
header img {
    width: 100px; /*Need give fixed width */
    height: auto;
}
```